# Does WooCommerce, BigCommerce or Magento offer a Multipass feature like Shopify Plus?

Tags: magento, woocommerce, shopify, bigcommerce, multipass

Shopify Plus has a feature called Multipass (https://shopify.dev/api/multipass) that's meant for store owners who have a separate website and a Shopify store. It redirects users from the website to the Shopify store and seamlessly logs them in with the same email address they used to sign up for the original website.

Does anyone know if WooCommerce, BigCommerce or Magento have a similar feature?

Comment: Woocommerce is a plugin to Wordpress. So your website is Wordpress and your shop is just extra pages. If you want to have em on separate addresses like domain.com (website) and shop.domain.com (shop) then you can use wordpress multisite option that have option to keep session between for users.

Comment: Did you come up  with a solution for this? Our use case is quite similar and not sure if this is possible in wordpress. Comments might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

BigCommerce has very similar functionality to allow this using the Customer Login API that uses JWT (JSON Web Tokens) to allow a customer to be logged in without requiring them to re-enter their credentials. There are a number of use-cases where this is useful, including the one you describe.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/customer-login-api